# Javascript string to array

Tags: javascript, charts

I get an variable  via ajax from php file

This is data for google column chart

When i use it for build chart - it doesn't work

But same data works fine, when i paste it directly

Here example:

```
$.get("./get_charts.php", function(data){
   //alert(data.daily) = [ ["12.10.2011", 2250],["07.12.2011", 100] ]
   drawChart('daily', 'number', 'Kgs', data.daily, 0);
}, "json"); 
}

function drawChart(ctype, col_type, col_name, cdata, baseline) 
{       
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn(col_type, col_name);
    //doesn't work
    data.addRows(cdata);
   //works fine
    data.addRows([ ["12.10.2011", 2250],["07.12.2011", 100] ]);
   ....
}
```

I guess it's because this variable is passed as string value, but not array

How to convert it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I think we would have to see what "data.daily" is. Can you tell us or do a console.log on it and paste the output?

Comment: when you give  "json" as data type it won't be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the function eval?

```
var result = eval(data);
```

or jquery has a parseJSON function.

this online parser uses both ways to get a json string to a variable:

http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that content type is **application/json**

then use

```
$.getJSON("./get_charts.php", function(data){
   //alert(data.daily) = [ ["12.10.2011", 2250],["07.12.2011", 100] ]
   drawChart('daily', 'number', 'Kgs', data.daily, 0);
});
```

If content type is correct your code should also work.
If it is coming as string, @Richard's solution will work.